# Style disappear for a moment on page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css

It's a simple html page and i'm changing the style sheet (switching between dark and light theme) on button click using the following functions:

```js
 function setDarkTheme() {
   document.getElementById('style1').href = "css/Dark.css";
   document.getElementById('style2').href = "css/skins/skin-dark.css"; 
  }
  
  function setDefaultTheme() {
   document.getElementById('style1').href = "css/Light.css";
   document.getElementById('style2').href = "css/skins/skin-light.css";
  }
```

Also, the current theme value is being saved in browser localstorage which is checked outside the jquery ready function to set the style-sheet before page is loaded (whenever user comes back to the site).

The problem (both on Chrome and firefox) is that when user switch to dark theme and refresh the page, styling disappear for a second and then comes back. If user switch back to light/default theme and refresh the page it works fine without any glitch. The default href value of style-sheet is set to the light theme in the html page.

Is there any way to get rid of that glitch ? Any suggestions will be great.

Comment: check n load your saved theme on window load

Comment: what are the default properties of `#style1`, `#style2`?

Comment: if i do it on load ,it  gives a flash of the default theme . I dont want that.

Comment: @donnikitos the default values of both styles are in the html page Link tag.

Comment: @johnny what are the default values? the light theme or the dark one?

Comment: @donnikitos light theme.

Comment: @johnny check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Since the default values of your `<link />` tags are the *.css files for the light theme they are being load by default, no matter if you change the value on `ready` or not. `ready` means the page is already loaded. And the  of each page is loaded first.

The suggestion is, to **leave the values of the `<link />` tags blank** in your HTML and load the proper *.css files only on page ready.

Comment: I tried your way but now it gives the glitch on both themes.

Comment: then I also would suggest you to hide everything first and then show it when the page is loaded, just to cover the glitch

Comment: @johnny also try to use not the `jQuery.ready()` event, but the `window.onload = function() {};` event, that might do it